# I would like to create a security domain on eUICC using ES3.CreateISDP function

Tags: smartcard, javacard, sim-card, telecommunication

I'm trying to create a new raw/empty ISD-P on eUICC. Correct me if I'm wrong, first I should send INSTALL COMMAND (i.e. 80.E6.0C.00.Length.DATA.00) to ISD-R through SCP80 channel (putting INSTALL COMMAND in the secured data field of command packet mentioned in ETSI TS 102 225). When I send the command accordingly, the eUICC responses SW1=6F SW2=00. What am I missing?

PS this is my APDU command to be sent through SCP80 channel to ISD-R:

```
INSTALL COMMAND: 80E60C003F10A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000D0010A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000E0010A0000005591010FFFFFFFF89000020000380C00006C904810203700000

CLA: 80
INS: E6
P1: 0C
P2:00
Length of command field: 3F

*Command field:*
Length of Executable Load File AID: 10
Executable Load File: A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000D00

Length of Executable Module AID:10
Executable Module: A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000E00

Length of Application AID: 10
Application AID (ISD-P-AID): A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900002000

Length of Privileges: 03
Privileges: 80 C0 00

Length of Install Parameters field:06
Install Parameters field: C90481020370
Length of Install Token: 00
```

Comment: Note that I don't like the nick and putting forth a bounty should not be considered an offering to Satan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my eUICC under the test only accepts APDUs in expanded mode.